# GAS Gmail to Drive: save attached zip file to Google Drive

Tags: google-apps-script, google-drive-api, gmail, email-attachments, unzip

I have emails coming in containing zip files. How could I unzip and save these files to a specific folder on Google Drive using Google Apps Script? The below code part works perfectly with simple excel/pdf files.

```
var root = DriveApp.getRootFolder();
  for(var i in threads){
    var mesgs = threads[i].getMessages();
    for(var j in mesgs){
      var attachments = mesgs[j].getAttachments();
      for(var k in attachments){
        var attachment = attachments[k];
        var isDefinedType = checkIfDefinedType_(attachment);
        if(!isDefinedType) continue;
        var attachmentBlob = attachment.copyBlob();
                
var existingFile = DriveApp.getFilesByName(attachment.getName());
if (existingFile.hasNext()) {
  var file = existingFile.next();
  file.setTrashed(true);
}
var file = DriveApp.createFile(attachmentBlob);
parentFolder.addFile(file);
root.removeFile(file);
```

Answer (score 1):

#### Answer:

*You can add files to a folder using `Utilities.unzip()`.*

#### Code Example:

```
var attachmentBlob = attachment.copyBlob();
var files = Utilities.unzip(attachmentBlob);

files.forEach(function(file) {
  DriveApp.createFile(file)
  parentFolder.addFile(file);
  root.removeFile(file);
});
```

#### References:

- [Class Utilities | Apps Script | Google Developers - `.unzip(blob)`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/utilities/utilities#unzipblob)